# How can I add a prebuilt static library in a project using CMake?

Tags: cmake, static-libraries, clion

[CLion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IDEs): How can I add (or use) a prebuilt static library in my project?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're asking about how to link your project to the pre-built static library, you can do like this by calling [**`target_link_libraries`**](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html).

Assume your project called `myProj` and the pre-built library `myLib.lib`, you can it do like this:

```
target_link_libraries(myProj myLib)
```

Comment: @Andreyua That will simply be `target_link_libraries(myProj /tmp/balabla/mylib.a)`. :)

Comment: @herohuyongtao I am still getting Following error  `cannot find -llibusb1.0`where my `target_link_libraries( native-lib libusb1.0)`error Can you help me plz?

Answer (score 10):

I had great difficulty making this work as I was completely new to CLion and CMake.

In my scenario I was taking a class that required us to use the course library in every project.

Assuming you have a library called `libClassLibrary.a`, do the following in the `CMakeLists.txt` at the project root:

First, find the library's location:

```
find_library(LIB_TO_INCLUDE ClassLibrary /path/to/your/library)
```

`LIB_TO_INCLUDE` will contain the location of the library assuming it is found.  Note that hardcoding the path could be problematic if you'd like your solution to be portable to other systems.  You can add additional search paths separated by a space if the library could exist in multiple locations.  A typical example is to include common install locations such as `/usr/bin /usr/local/bin` etc.

Next, ensure that header files (if applicable) are included in the header search paths:

```
find_path (LIB_INCLUDES ClassLibrary.h /path/to/header/files)
```

Again, include multiple search paths if the headers could be loaded in multiple locations.  If there is more than one header file, you'll need to include all of them.

Now, include the directories using the `include_directories` command:

```
include_directories(${LIB_INCLUDES})
```

The above will instruct the build system to search all directories contained in `LIB_INCLUDES` or whatever you decide to call it.

Finally, add the executable and use the `target_link_libraries` command to link the `libClassLibrary.a`.

```
add_executable(MyExecutable main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MyExecutable ${LIB_TO_INCLUDE})
```

That's all.  You'll notice that under "External Libraries" > "Header Search Paths" in the Project organizer window the directories containing your header files appears.

PS - The book **Mastering CMake** by Ken Martin and Bill Hoffmann is an invaluable resource.

Answer (score 4):

I've linked my static lib `test.a` with the related header files as following:

```
Project
├── main.cpp
├── CmakeLists.txt
├── libs
│   ├── includes
│   │   ├── *.h
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── test.a
```

I've added this to the `./CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/include)
find_library(Test_LIB test "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/lib")
add_executable(TestApp main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(TestApp ${Test_LIB})
```

By adding `message(${Test_LIB})`, you can print out and check the path.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unrelated to CLion; it is pure CMake. Modify the CMakeLists.txt from your project and use `add_library`. The [CMake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/add_library.html) might be helpful.

I misunderstood the question; `target_link_library` is probably the answer to the question.

Comment: `add_library` is for building your own library.  As @herohuyongtao stated, the answer is to use `target_link_libraries` to add libraries to the link line for a target.